# I'm writing a letter for my test and confusing if i should use"and also it" or "and it also"

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

> Shwezigon Pagoda's appearance always makes me feel powerful. *And it also* made me consider how mighty Bagan and our nations were back in those days.

Or should I be using "and also it" here? Does it make a difference?

Comment: I doubt many if any native speakers would notice or care whether you wrote *And it also...* or *And also it...* in the cited context. But they'll *all* notice the unusual switch from Present Tense ***makes** me feel...* to Past Tense ***made** me consider...* You could get away with that if the first sentence has been true for the speaker for a long time, but the second sentence specifically refers to some recent contextually identified exposure to Shwezigon Pagoda. But that's an unlikely context, and it's even more unlikely you'd want to reflect it by using those two different tenses.

Answer (score 1):

If I were reading the second sentence out aloud, I'd use

- "And it also made/makes ..."

or

- "And also, it made/makes ..." (note the pause I'd insert with this ordering, coded for by the comma)

(note also that I'd want consistency with the 'always makes' of the first sentence).

Some would say that the use of *both* 'and' and 'also' here is tautology. It is, but it's also totally idiomatic, acceptable, and some would consider makes for a smoother-flowing style than using 'and' or 'also' (or sentence initial 'too'!) alone.